# How to initialize JSON file from web service?

Tags: spring-mvc, angular7, primeng

I have an application using angular 7 front part and spring MVC back part.I'm using Primeng to display tables.As an improuvement,  I want to display `[value]="guichetOuvertModels"` from a JSON file:

```
  <p-table #GestionProfilTable [columns]="cols" [value]="gestionProfilList" [lazy]="false"
                         [paginator]="true" [rows]="10"  selectionMode="single"
                         [scrollable]="false" [responsive]="true"
                         (onRowSelect)="someClickHandlerGuichetTable($event)" 
          [(selection)]="selectedGuichet" dataKey="id"
                         (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" [customSort]="true">
```

This json file is a result of a web service, like this:

```
 getListProfils() {
  return this.http.get<Array<GestionProfilModel>>(this.profilUrl + 
 'getAllGroupesUserProfils').toPromise();
 }
```

Comment: Hope you have added a model file to achieve this

Comment: @RagavanRajan sorry i didn't understand